# compare values in array and delete it from array - php

Tags: php, arrays

array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => 70H
        [2] => 51.57
        [3] => RH
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => 70H
        [2] => 39.11
        [3] => RH
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => C
        [1] => 70H
        [2] => 12.11
        [3] => RH
    )
```

This is just an example of an array, my real array is really big.

I want to find the same values in array like this [key][1], compare their price, find the lowest PRICE [KEY][2]and save [key][0] for all other elements, if the price is the same then random save one as lowest. In the example i give the result that i want will be:

```
[0] A
[1] B
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work for me:

```
$res=array();
$Mfr= arrays_column($final_array, 1);
$dupes = array_diffs(array_count_values($Mfr), array(1)); // how many times a mfr sku appears 
print "\nThese are repetitive values:\n[mfrsku] => (number of reps)\n";
foreach($dupes as $key => $val){
    $temp = array_intersect_key(arrays_column($final_array, 3), $key); 
    if(count(array_unique($temp)) < count($temp)){

        $temp = array_intersect_key(arrays_column($final_array, 2), array_intersect($Mfr, array($key)));
        $temp = array_diffs($temp, array(min($temp)));
        $res[] = array_intersect_key(arrays_column($final_array, 0), $temp);
        print_r($res);die;
    }
}
```

Comment: `array_column` instead of `arrays_column`; `array_diff` instead of `array_diffs`; error in `array_intersect_key(arrays_column($final_array, 3), $key);` -> `$key` need to be an array etc. Here too much array functions, it could be done more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect during first `foreach` loop all minimum values and then easily collect records which have another values:

Declaring arrays

```
$minvals = [];     // array of minimum values
$spec = [];        // resultant array
$tmp = [];         // tmp array (needs for similar records)
```

First array (collecting minimum values(prices)):

```
foreach($ar as $rec){
    $val = $rec[2];                       // price

    if(isset($minvals[$rec[1]] )) {       // next appearance of the same $rec[1]
        if ($minvals[$rec[1]] >= $val) { 
            $minvals[$rec[1]] = $val;   
        }
    } else {                              // first appearance 
        $minvals[$rec[1]] = $val;
    } 
}
```

Now you can collect desired values of from the first column:

```
foreach($ar as $rec){
    if ($rec[2] > $minvals[$rec[1]]){           // if price is bigger than minimum  
        $spec[] = $rec[0];
    } else if($rec[2] == $minvals[$rec[1]]){    // if equal
        if(isset($tmp[$rec[1]])){               // if it appears at not the first time
            $spec[] = $rec[0];
        } else {
            $tmp[$rec[1]] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In case of input array like:

```
$ar = [ ["A","70H","51.57","RH"],
        ["B","70H","39.11","RH"],
        ["C","70H","12.11","RH"],

        ["A2","71H","11.57","RH"],
        ["B2","71H","32.11","RH"],

        ["C2","73H","12.11","RH"], 
        ["C3","73H","11.11","RH"], 
        ["C4","73H","33.11","RH"],  
        ["C5","73H","3.11","RH"],  
        ["C6","73H","3.11","RH"],         
      ];
```

Outputs would be next:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => B2
    [3] => C2
    [4] => C3
    [5] => C4
    [6] => C6
)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UnbKL)**